wix Install .exePackage after Extracting files
I have a file named CDM212364_Setup.exe which I need to extract first and then I need to install a generated subfile dpinst-amd64.exe file silently. I am downloading the .exe from FTDI. After I extract CDM212364_Setup.exe with 7-zip, it generates a folder like this shown below. Now I want to install dpinst-amd64.exe within that folder.

Using this code below is very tedious to include each and every folder and subfolder to the the payload,
<ExePackage Id="FTDIDriversInstaller"
                  SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\dpinst-amd64.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/q /se"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Compressed="yes">
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftcserco.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftcserco.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftd2xx.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftd2xx.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="amd64\ftbusui.dll" SourceFile="amd64\ftbusui.dll" />
               <Payload Name="FTDIDrivers_Setup\i386" SourceFile="FTDIDrivers_Setup\i386" />
               <Payload Name="FTDIDrivers_Setup\Static" SourceFile="FTDIDrivers_Setup\Static" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\dp-chooser.exe" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\dpinst.xml" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\ftd2xx.h" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\ftdibus.cat" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\ftdibus.inf" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\ftdiport.xml" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\ftdiport.inf" />
               <Payload SourceFile="\licence.txt" />
      </ExePackage>

I see wix has something like InstallPackage class which has ExtractFiles method. Can I use this mechanishm to install the dpinst-amd64.exe file after extracting. If so can anyone help me with an example how to achieve this. I am using .net framework 4.7.2 with wix version 3.11

You may consider specifying whether you're using .NET Framework or .NET (and which version). Also specify what version of Wix Toolset you're using.

I have edited my post with those details.

Since the folder structure of ftd2xx drivers did not change the last 10 years or so this solution should be fine and it also does not introduce additional dependencies.

I fixed my issue by using a Self Extracting Executable using 7-zip.
